# Where are stored the linux container volumes under windows?

Tags: docker

I state that I'm quite new to docker, I need to run an OTRS docker image that hosts the file inside a volume, but it's not clear to me where those files are stored inside windows.

I need to know this since I wish to perform a backup of the files... 
The compose is [here](https://github.com/juanluisbaptiste/docker-otrs/blob/master/docker-compose-prod.yml)

I've seen that there's under C:\ProgramData\Docker\volumes but seems empty...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

for this example the volumes will be created and  stored in current directory. 
Like it written in this line https://github.com/juanluisbaptiste/docker-otrs/blob/master/docker-compose-prod.yml#L22
so that line meant in current directory if there are volumes folder use it otherwise create an empty directory and mount it to container.

Comment: line22 is of skins... but on a wi dows system where do I find them?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve a time to read the  [**about page**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [**how to write a good answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in order to help, not only the user who asked the question, but many more that have similar issues.